# Хранимая процедура, которая будет выводить сумму 2 чисел при определенном условии

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица **ПРЕДМЕТЫ** и **ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ**. В таблице **ПРЕДМЕТЫ** есть поля *Колво_лекций* и *Колво_практик*, а в таблице **ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ** поля *Лекции* и *Практики* (тип данных  bool).

---

Моя процедура должна выводить сумму *Колво_лекций* и *Колво_практик*, если *Лекции* и *Практики* равны единице, либо должно вывести только *Колво_лекций*, если только *Лекции* = 1 или только *Колво_практик*, если только Практики = 1. Входные параметры (id предмета). Помогите найти ошибки в процедуре, потому что она выдает неверные результаты.

Мои таблицы:

```
   CREATE TABLE `ПРЕДМЕТЫ` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Назв_предмета` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Колво_лекций` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Колво_практик` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Лабы` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ДЗ` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Назв_предмета` (`Назв_предмета`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



CREATE TABLE `ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ФИО` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Должность` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ID_предмета` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ID_кафедры` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Лекции` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `Практики` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `Дипломники` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Курсовики` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `ID_предмета` (`ID_предмета`),
  KEY `ID_кафедры` (`ID_кафедры`),
  CONSTRAINT `преподаватели_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_предмета`) REFERENCES `ПРЕДМЕТЫ` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `преподаватели_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_кафедры`) REFERENCES `КАФЕДРЫ` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

А вот процедура:

```
    DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `WorkTime`(IN VAR_ID INT)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    SET @a = (SELECT ПРЕДМЕТЫ.`Колво_лекций` FROM ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ JOIN ПРЕДМЕТЫ WHERE ПРЕДМЕТЫ.ID=VAR_ID AND ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ.`ID_предмета`= VAR_ID);
    SET @b = (SELECT ПРЕДМЕТЫ.`Колво_практик` FROM ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ JOIN ПРЕДМЕТЫ WHERE ПРЕДМЕТЫ.ID = VAR_ID AND ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ.`ID_предмета`= VAR_ID);
    SET @result = (SELECT @a+@b FROM ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ where ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ.`Лекции`=1 AND ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ.`Практики`=1 );
    SET @result = (SELECT @a FROM ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ where ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ.`Лекции`=1 AND ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ.`Практики`=0);
    SET @result = (SELECT @b FROM ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ where ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ.`Лекции`=0 AND ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ.`Практики`=1);
    SELECT ФИО, @result FROM ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ join ПРЕДМЕТЫ where ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ.`ID_предмета`= VAR_ID AND ПРЕДМЕТЫ.ID = VAR_ID;
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что когда 3 раза подряд делаете `set @result = ...` то в переменной содержится результат последнего set, а два предыдущих можно просто удалить из процедуры и от этого ничего не измениться

Comment: И еще совершенно не ясно, что должно получиться на выходе процедуры. сейчас она дает выборку в которой присутствуют ФИО всех преподавателей данного предмета напротив которых одна и та же переменная @result. В такой выборке явно нет никакого смысла

Comment: А вообще обратите внимание, то в MySQL работают правила математики и при умножении на 1 число остается самим собой, а при умножении на 0 дает 0. И с учетом этого возможно вся процедура сводится к `SELECT ФИО, ПРЕДМЕТЫ.Колво_лекций * ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ.Лекции + ПРЕДМЕТЫ.Колво_практик * ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ.Практики FROM ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ join ПРЕДМЕТЫ where ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ.ID_предмета= VAR_ID AND ПРЕДМЕТЫ.ID = VAR_ID;` Если конечно на выходе действительно нужен список преподавателей с числами, а не что то другое

Comment: Вы просто спасли мне жизнь. И в правду, вы абсолютно правы, буду внимательней в следующий раз. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Так же обращаю ваше внимание, что использовать в процедурах MySQL переменные с @ не стоит. они используются для совершенно других целей, они хранят результаты между вызовами разных запросов и процедур. А внутри процедур стоит использовать процедурные переменные, объявляемые declare и не имеющих @ в названиях

Comment: Ага, возьму на заметку. Спасибо)